# How to change the console window title of a dotnet application run by powershell?

Tags: powershell, console, .net-6.0, title

I'm launching multiple `dotnet run` commands using a Powershell script.

```
$projectsRootDirectory = "$PSScriptRoot\.."

Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' `
              -WorkingDirectory "$projectsRootDirectory\SomeProjectFolder" `
              -ArgumentList 'run --launch-profile My.Profile --debug'
```

When I launch 6 of them simultaneously I have a problem distinguishing which one is which.

From questions like this one, I learned it is possible with the -c parameter:

```
Start-Process powershell '-c "$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = \"Speed Test\"; .\SpeedTest.ps1"'
```

But as far as I understand, the -c parameter is for the `powershell` command. Can I achieve the same with `dotnet run` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the simplest solution is to call `cmd.exe`'s CLI in order to call its internal [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command, which is comparable to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) while allowing you to set the console window title *directly*:

```bash
$projectsRootDirectory = "$PSScriptRoot\.."

cmd /c @"
start /d "$projectsRootDirectory\SomeProjectFolder" "Speed Test" dotnet run --launch-profile My.Profile --debug
"@
```

- Note the use of a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to make use of embedded quoting easier.
- Following any of it owns options - such as `/d` to set the working directory for the new process - `start` interprets an immediately following `"..."`-enclosed argument as the title for the new console window with all remaining arguments constituting the executable to start plus any arguments.

  - Note that options such as `/d` must come *before* a window title / the executable plus arguments to start.
- `Start-Process`, by contrast, does *not* support setting a console window title for applications, so the only way to do that is to have  *the newly launched process itself* change the title; if that process is also a *shell* (`cmd.exe` or the PowerShell CLI, `powershell.exe` / `pwsh.exe`), you can use the latter's features to do that (`title Speed Tests` or `[Console]::Title = 'Speed Test'`).
  While you could use this technique to *indirectly* launch the target executable, the above technique is simpler.